# How to iterate over a specific set of keys in c++ maps?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I am iterating over a C++ map. Say I want to obtain the keys present in the map except the first 2. The keys are sorted in map. Hence I thought of using something like this:

```
map<int, int> table;
for( auto i = table.begin()+2; i != table.end(); i++ )
  cout<<i->first<<"\t"<<i->second<<endl;
```

Though this works with vectors, it throws an error with maps due to the '+' operator not being implemented for maps. One way the result can be achieved is :

```
auto i = table.begin();
int count = 0;
while( count < 2 && i != table.end() ){
  count++;
  i++;
}
for( ; i!=table.end(); i++ )
  cout<<i->first<<"\t"<<i->second<<endl;
```

Is there any other efficient way to implement this?

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time thinking of a use-case for this; are you sure `map` is even the right data structure here? `map`s in C++ do happen to be iterable in order, but `map` operations that can't also be done with `unordered_map`s make me a little queasy, because the point of a `map` is *not* to be an ordered set of tuples (that's more or less what `priority_queue` is for) but to be a *mapping* from keys to values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's no more efficient but perhaps a little easier to read

```
for (auto i = std::next(table.begin(), 2); i != table.end(); i++)
```

Comment: upvoted because this will generalize to other containers, e.g. `std::vector` where the `std::next` will simply delegate to `begin() + 2`. Two nitpicks: I'd prefer to use the name `it` and use `i` for loop indices, because it's less surprising for people used to STL based iterator loops. Also: prefer `++it` instead of `it++`.